# Returning a collection which has name property and repetition times

Tags: neo4j, cypher

```
start n=node(22), p=node(1) match n<-[r1:FOLLOWS]-m-[r2:HAS]->k<-[r3:CONTAIN]-p return distinct [k.name]
```

I'm trying to return the names and repetition times of k values here and so far, I could not manage to do it. Is there a quick way to do it with cypher query?

Consider this example:

```
["Acting","Acting","Acting","Acting","Mongodb","Mongodb","Neo4j","Neo4j","Nursing"]
```

I'm trying to have something like:

```
[["Acting",4], ["Mongodb",2], ["Neo4j",2], ["Nursing",1]]
```

Note: The same names (property) indicate the same node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it! :)

```
start n=node(22), p=node(1) match n<-[r1:FOLLOWS]-m-[r2:HAS]->k<-[r3:CONTAIN]-p return distinct [k.name] as skill, count(k) as count
```

Answer (score 0):

And in case you ever want to further filter on the counts (say you only want results where the count is greater than 5, you could also wrap it in a WITH statement. Nice and tidy.

```
    START n=node(22), p=node(1) 
    MATCH n<-[r1:FOLLOWS]-m-[r2:HAS]->k<-[r3:CONTAIN]-p 
    WITH distinct [k.name] as skill, count(k) as count
    WHERE count > 5
    RETURN skill, count
```